# Как инициализировать класс?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
    {
        static Box box;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool loop = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите длину коробки: ");
            int Length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите ширину коробки: ");
            int Width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите высоту коробки: ");
            int Heigth = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Box box = new Box();

            while (loop)
            {
                PrintMenu();
                string menu = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                switch(menu)
                {
                    case "1":
                        GetVolume();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        GetSideSurface();
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        GetSurfaceArea();
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        loop = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Вылетело из головы, какой синтаксис инициализации. Класс - "Box", то, что я написал неправильно, я знаю.

Comment: покажите класс `Box`... у вас явно что то лишнее. Указать величины можно после `Box box = new Box();` => `box.Width = 20;`. Но строка `static Box box;` сбивает с пути ) она либо не нужна, либо дальше не правильно

Answer (score 0):

у вас класс Box статичный `static Box` он инициализируется при запуске программы
для доступа к его методам и атрибутам используйте `.` пример=> `Box.YourMethod()`
Данный тип класса может существовать **только в одном экземпляре !!!**